# How to insert an expression in a Mathematica program?

Tags: programming, syntax

I need to insert a very large expression in a *Mathematica* program. So I first 
Put[large expression,"file"] 
and then use

```
Block[{}, Get["file"];...]
```

to implement the function. But the variables here is not local variables and may interact with other programs. I have tried to use

```
Module[{},Get["file"];...],
```

but it does not work. Do you know a clever way to do this?

Comment: I know some. But I do not know how to solve this problem with Packages and Contexts. Can you teach me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have tried this example and the result is 22 a b + 56 c + 13 a d. The value a=1 is not used and this is just my question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! For improving your experience in this site, I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help:

```
Block[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Get["ExampleData/language"]]
```

or

```
Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Evaluate@Get["ExampleData/language"]]
```

If you want your variables to be global, simply

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;
<< ExampleData/language
```

Comment: I think the form Module[{}, Evaluate@Get["file"]] is just what I need! And dose this equal to directly copy the file in the program? I usually store some very large expressions in the file and then call it to do the numerical calculation.

Comment: I find a new problem now. When I try to do Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4,x}, x=Evaluate@Get["ExampleData/language"]], the result is still 22 a b + 56 c + 13 a d not 264. Why it can not assign the value of a large expression to a variable? And I often need this assignment in my program. Can you help me?

Comment: @wxg: I think the `Block` version is what you want. This is one of the rare cases where `Block` is better suited than `Module`. While the `Module` version will in principle work, it will use the global definitions of the local variables if they exists, due to the `Evaluate`. It will also stop working when you add to the body and `Evaluate` isn't at the right level anymore...

Comment: Note: `Module[{x}, x]` vs `Block[{x}, x]`. The `x` inside Module is not symbolic `x`, it's a unique symbol.

Comment: Thank belisarius. I find my problem can be easily solved by making the program to a small package.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `With`, but note that the `Evaluate` piece is essential for both `Module` and `With`. Compare:

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Get["ExampleData/language"]]

(* 22 a b + 56 c + 13 a d *)
```

With:

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, 
 Evaluate@Get["ExampleData/language"]]

(* 264 *)
```

Depending on the size of your problem and the number of replacements you need to make, you could also consider `ReplaceAll`.

```
Get["ExampleData/language"] /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4}

(* 264 *)
```